# bluetooth automatic turn on and turn off

Tags: android, android-activity

automatic turn on Bluetooth and after some time it should turn off automatically.

Is it possible in android programming?

i tried this `BA = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()`;

```
BA = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

if (!BA.isEnabled()) {
    BA.enable();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth switched On", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} if(BA.isEnabled())  {

    BA.disable();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth switched On", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

This will turn on the Bluetooth but it does not turning off...in the second run of the application it is turning off..

Answer (score 0):

No you can't, with the latest marshmallow update you need the permission unless the user is comfortable